How to Implement a Single Unleash Client Instance in Next.js App Router
I am experiencing timeouts in my Unleash server. My Next.js app maxed out at ~150rps which is absurdly low. I suspect this is due to my app having multiple client instances.
I've implemented Unleash in my Next.js app's this way as per the documentation of @unleash/next.js.
Dependencies
- "@unleash/nextjs": "^1.4.1"
- "next": "14.2.3" (I use App router)


export default async function getFlag(): Promise<{
  isEnabled: (name: string) => boolean
  getVariant: (name: string) => IVariant
}> {
  const sessionId = `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 1_000_000_000)}`

  try {
    const definitions = await getDefinitions({
      fetchOptions: {
        next: { revalidate: 0 },
      },
    })

    const { toggles } = evaluateFlags(definitions, {
      sessionId,
    })
    const flags = flagsClient(toggles)

    return flags
  } catch (e) {
    
  }
}


export default async function Layout(props: PropsWithChildren) {
  const flag = await getFlag();

// use the flag here
  return <SomeComponent />;
}

My questions are

Is my implementation really uses multiple clients (and resulted to my Unleash server blown out) ?
If so, then how can I use only a single client for all route handlers in Next.js SSR app ?

Thanks
